# Почему в теге title страницы не выводится значение "Шаблон META TITLE" из вкладки SEO инфоблока

Tags: битрикс

Такая ситуация: в инфоблоке во вкладке SEO в разделе "Настройки для элементов" в поле "Шаблон META TITLE" прописано: {=this.Name} | *текст* .

В публичной части есть раздел с компонентом bitrix:news.list, который берет инфу из того инфоблока, в котором я seo прописал. По идее, когда переходишь на детальную инфу о конкретном элементе, должен title браться из настроек инфоблока. И так оно и было, но потом я изменил заголовок и свойства страницы с компонентом и после этого в title на детальной странице есть только {=this.Name}, а обратно поменять не получается.

Я новичок в битриксе, пока очень плохо представляю что к чему, понимаю, что вопрос мой, скорее всего очень глупый и действия мои тоже, но все же требуется решение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

возможные причины:
1. В настройках компонента нету параметров отвечающих за вывод title https://yadi.sk/i/Cgz2O31MxoRIYg
2. Возможно вы изменили шаблон вывода компонента отвечающего за вывод детальной страницы, и там устанавливается свой title посмотрите в шаблоне есть ли метод `SetTitle` или `SetPageProperty` они отвечают да отложенный вывод title

Answer (score 0):

Вы упомянули, что для вывода списка новостей используется компонент bitrix:news.list, который собственно отвечает за вывод списка. Но вывод детальной карточки элемента осуществляется другим компонентом, расположенным скорее всего на другой странице.

Попробуйте посмотреть, указано ли в настройка компонента детального просмотра устанавливать Title, и проверьте, чтобы после вызова этого компонента не было других компонентов, меняющих Title, или чтобы не было явных вызовов метода **SetTitle**.